# How to upload file to Google code hosting using php script

Tags: php, google-code

I have account on google code, and create a project,
I want upload file to Hosting on google code?
Please help me find solutions.

Comment: Does google-code have an API? If yes, it will be documented. If not, you're out of luck.

Answer (score 0):

A Google employee has come up with a Python script, the detail is at 
http://code.google.com/p/support/wiki/ScriptedUploads

According to the author, the main logic is at function "upload".